# How can I limit javafx bar-chart axis label size?

Tags: javafx, bar-chart

I have a bar chart with a category axis which is dynamically populated with data.

Problem is when data text is too long, the whole chart moves up to accommodate the label size like so:[image]

I've tried to search for a way to limit the label size (possibly clip the text with ...) but to no avail.

I've also searched for the actual node via chart.lookupAll method but it appears the node is of type Text which cannot be resized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use "text.setWrappingWidth(200)" http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works well when the labels are horizontal (i.e. when they have room), however, when they are vertical (like in my image above), the text is indeed wrapped but the label size is still large